# Mask RCNN compatability issues with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, compatibility

I'm trying to run Mask-RCNN on a jupyter notebook (on colab). 
Im using the following repository: `!git clone https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.git` 
there are a few changes that need to be done to make it run properly, for example changing the KE.Layer cases to KE.base_layer.Layer in the model.py file.

but still, at the end the following error is shown:

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.math.truediv/truediv:0', description="created by layer 'tf.math.truediv'") of unsupported type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383964/typeerror-could-not-build-a-typespec-with-type-kerastensor), which claims that this is a compatibility issue.

That pulled me into a vicious-cycle of compatibility issues, and still no working solution:

first, I then figured out that the `requirements.text` file is not being used at all, because of other compatibility issues with the `parse_requirements` method in the pip package, and the solution for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971236) (answer by @sinoroc).

Second, when I'm trying to use an older version of tensorflow, it does not find any:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.3.0 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)`  (only v2+).
This -can- be circumvented by `!pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl`

BUT there are two following issues:

1 - I need it as part of the `requirements.txt` file in the maskrcnn folder, and I am not able to make it run from there.

2 - this also creates compatibility issues: 
`ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. kapre 0.3.7 requires tensorflow>=2.0.0, but you have tensorflow 1.14.0 which is incompatible.`

**Question:** is there a way to resolve these issues? maybe there is an updated Mask-RCNN version that resolves these compatibilities?

It is crucial for me that the solution will be able to **accept custom classes** (my data is coco style, but with custom classes) and be able to **run on a colab notebook**.

Comment: As the error states you can try again by upgrading the `Tensorflow version > 2.0` compatible to the installed python version of your system . Please check this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67575203/14290681) for your reference.